# angularjs get the error message from the service to the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-resource

Factory that gets the rates using REST

```
.factory('rateResource', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/rates/:currency/:effectiveDate', {
        currency: '@currency',
        effectiveDate: '@effectiveDate'
    });
}])
```

Service that calls the factory to get resource and retrieve the rates and also errors if there are any.

```
 .service('RateService', ['rateResource', '$rootScope',
    function (rateResource, $rootScope) {
        var self = this;

        self.rates = [];

        self.search = function (baseCurrency, effectiveDate) {
            self.rates = [];
            var error = null;
            self.baseCurrency = baseCurrency;
            self.effectiveDate = effectiveDate;
            if (baseCurrency) {
                rateResource.query({currency: baseCurrency, effectiveDate: effectiveDate})
                    .$promise.then(function (rates) {
                        if (rates) {
                            angular.forEach(rates, function (rate) {
                                rate.maintTs = $rootScope.formatTimestampToHHMMSS(rate.maintTs);
                                rate.editable = false;
                                self.rates.push(rate);
                            });
                            self.processing = false;
                        }
                    }, function (response) {
                        self.processing = false;
                        error = 'Processing failed due to '+response.status;
                        console.log(error);
                    })
                return {
                    rates: self.rates,
                    errors: error
                }
            }
        }
    }]);
```

Controller calls the service for rates.

```
.controller('RateController', ['RateService',
    function (rateService) {
        var self = this;

        self.baseCurrency = rateService.getBaseCurrency();
        self.effectiveDate = rateService.getEffectiveDate();
        self.rates = rateService.getRates();

        //make the call from the controller
        self.search = function () {
            var response = rateService.search(self.baseCurrency, self.effectiveDate.yyyyMMdd());
            self.rateRecords = response.rates;
            self.errors = response.errors;
        }
    }])
```

rates are showing up fine in the controller after the promise is fulfilled. However, upon receiving errors, they are not getting transferred from service to controller. ( I changed the REST URL to make service return a 404 response ). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you can not get `self.rates` value outside promise function..because they are filling up asynchronously.

Comment: self.rates is working fine for me; After the promise is fulfilled, I can see the rates in the display via the controller. The issue is with errors

Comment: Ohh.. `self.rates` working fine because you are passing `self.rates` reference.. what errors you are talking about..?

Comment: I would like to pass error = 'Processing failed due to '+response.status; message to the controller. I simulated 404 by making a request to an invalid url, but, the error is not being sent to the controller.

Comment: look at the answer which I've added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you are returning asynchronous call response from outside of async function, you shouldn't do that technically. Asynchronous code always get there responses inside their `promise`/`callback` function.

But in your case it is working because you are returning object with it reference. If you look at below code, `return` statement has carried `self.rates` object reference, so while returning even if it is blank, it is going to get updated value once `self.rates` gets filled up. So then you don't need to worry about the `rates` updation. But same thing for error would not work because it is of primitive `datatype` like `var error = null`, so when you are returning value it would be `null`(as async response haven't completed).

```
return {
     rates: self.rates, //passed by reference
     errors: error //passed by primitive type
}
```

So for solving this issue you could also make the error to an `object` type, so that it reference will get passed with reference object, like `var errors = []` & when error occur push the error message into that array using `.push`

---

**But I'd not recommend above way to go for**, I'd rather take use of promise pattern and will maintain proper code call stack. Basically for that you need to return promise from `search` method & then put `.then` function to wait till resolve that function.

**Service**

```
.service('RateService', ['rateResource', '$rootScope',
    function(rateResource, $rootScope) {
      var self = this;
      self.rates = [];
      self.search = function(baseCurrency, effectiveDate) {
        self.rates = [];
        var error = null;
        self.baseCurrency = baseCurrency;
        self.effectiveDate = effectiveDate;
        if (baseCurrency) {
          return rateResource.query({
            currency: baseCurrency,
            effectiveDate: effectiveDate
          })
            .$promise.then(function(rates) {
            if (rates) {
              angular.forEach(rates, function(rate) {
                rate.maintTs = $rootScope.formatTimestampToHHMMSS(rate.maintTs);
                rate.editable = false;
                self.rates.push(rate);
              });
              self.processing = false;
            }
            //returning object from promise
            return {
              rates: self.rates,
              errors: error
            }
          }, function(response) {
            self.processing = false;
            error = 'Processing failed due to ' + response.status;
            console.log(error);
            //returning object from promise
            return {
              rates: self.rates,
              errors: error
            }
          })
        }
      }
    }
])
```

**Controller**

```
//make the call from the controller
self.search = function() {
  var response = rateService.search(self.baseCurrency, self.effectiveDate.yyyyMMdd()).then(function() {
    self.rateRecords = response.rates;
    self.errors = response.errors;
  });
}
```